# Create USB device protected by password, but readable/writable on multiple OS?

Tags: usb, windows, encryption, macosx, fat32

I've some problems to format a USB device as I want.
I need to obtain a USB device FAT 32 (readable and writable on Linux, MacOs and Windows) but protected with a password (encrypted).
I'm trying to format it with software "Disk"(Ububtu): if I choose FAT 32 not LUKS protected, the USB flash run on every OS (MacOs and Windows); but If I encrypt the device FAT 32 with LUKS protection, it works on my Linux pc only, and it's impossible to use the USB device on other computers.
My aim is to insert the flash drive on a pc (regardless the operating system), type my password and work (saving and editing files).
Is it possible ?
I'm not an expert... can someone help me please?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don’t think this is possible in practical terms - I’ve never been able to use a software encrypted device across multiple OS’s.

What does work is a hardware encrypted device - I’ve used a keypad encrypted hdd (connected via USB C) to store data - and as the encryption / decryption is independent of the OS, once it’s decrypted it behaves as any external drive in whatever computer you connect it to - ie if using ntfs or fat, it should be accessible in different OS’s. I’ve been able to read / write data to files created with Ubuntu using a windows computer with this strategy.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot for your advice. With MacOs I usually created an encrypted volume (protected by password) with ".dmg" extension and I saved it on the USB device. Maybe I can try something similar with Linux... but I've not yet found online how to do it with Linux.

Answer (score 1):

You could have a look at [VeraCrypt](https://www.veracrypt.fr/en/Home.html) which allows encrypting entire partitions or drives, and works on Windows and Linux.

To share data between Windows and Linux, I suggest creating an encrypted container (basically just a large encrypted file that acts like a partition) on a flash drive, or on a partition that is accessible from both Windows and Linux, using VeraCrypt. Make sure to format it with a filesystem that both OS's can use, preferably FAT32.

The advantage of a container is that it is movable, thus easily backed-up for example.

Comment: Veracrypt works on both Linux and Windows (and indeed Mac os), but I don’t think an encrypted container from one system is readable / writable by another. So you can use any OS with veracrypt to encrypt a usb, but my understanding is that you’re then limited to that os for that device (or partition). If I’m wrong, please do correct me!

Comment: I'll try Veracrypt too for experiment, but sincerely I don't like to rely completely on a software.... I'm convincing myself the best option maybe is to use a keypad encrypted hdd (as suggested by Will in the previous answer), or to copy temporary files on a FAT32 non encrypted device, pass them by linux pc on my ext4 encrypted USB device and format securely the previous USB flash (not encrypted) to erase completely copied files. So, working in progress... We'll see what happens. Thank you all.

Comment: @Will That is not how I understand it. I have not tried encrypting an entire device like that, but I have encrypted containers using VeraCrypt and used them on both Windows and Linux. VeraCrypt is actually the only software known to me that allows doing that easily.

Comment: @chrisfree23 I suggest trying to create an encrypted container (basically just a large encrypted file that acts like a disk partition) on a flash drive using VeraCrypt. That may already respond to your need. Fully encrypting an entire drive is not always needed, and the advantage is that your encrypted container is portable, thus easily backed-up for example.

Comment: @chrisfree23 - did this work for you? If it did, please accept Sebastian’s answer. If not, let us know. Thanks!